# Can't find HttpServerUtility class in System.Web in C#

Tags: c#, urldecode, httpserverutility

I'm trying to call the [HttpServerUtuility.URLDecode function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(VS.80,loband).aspx) in C# using Visual Studio 2005, but it can't be found.  I'm `using System.Web` properly, but the class doesn't seem to be there.  Do I need to add some sort of reference to my project?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few points:

- You need a reference to the `System.Web` assembly
- You need to get the class name right (`HttpServerUtility`, not `HttpServerUtuility`)
- You need to get the method name right (`UrlDecode`, not `URLDecode`)
- You need an instance of the class, as it's an instance method

Getting an instance is likely to be the hardest part, unless you're in ASP.NET - it doesn't have any public constructors or a static property to fetch an instance. Usually you'd use [`HttpContext.Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.server.aspx). An alternative is to use [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx), which *is* a static method. (Again, you'll need a reference to `System.Web`.)

Answer (score 6):

Add a reference to the System.Web assembly.

Comment: Then type HttpServerUtility and press "CTRL + .". Works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add assemblies to my web api

```
System.Web
System.Web.Abstractions
System.Web.ApplicationServices
```