# ASP.NET server object not visible in a C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET WEB application and I added a Class to that app.

Lets call it a.cs

In this class in have:

```
using System.Web;
```

Still for the following line:

```
Server.MapPath("~\\bin\\error.txt")
```

I get  "The name Server does not exist in the current context"

I researched further for the server object but I was directed to :

```
HttpServerUtility Class
```

Which appears to have all of the interface of the Server class.

Question: are these same `HttpServerUtility`  and Server?

Why `Server` itself give me the mentioned error?

`HttpServerUtility` Class is accessible in the a.cs.

=======================
The suggested duplicate  solution is not a solution in my case: There the accepted answer is:

You need a reference to the System.Web assembly
You need to get the class name right (HttpServerUtility, not HttpServerUtuility)
You need to get the method name right (UrlDecode, not URLDecode)
You need an instance of the class, as it's an instance method

None of above apply in my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find HttpServerUtility class in System.Web in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368596/cant-find-httpserverutility-class-in-system-web-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Server` is of type `HttpServerUtility` is a property of the [`Page` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.server(v=vs.110).aspx), and is set up by ASP.NET as part of the request lifecycle. To get an instance of `HttpServerUtility` in a standalone class you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server`. Like this:

```
var server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
```

Or in your class's functions, accept a context parameter.

```
public static void DoStuff(HttpContext context)
{
    var server = context.Server;
}
```

Comment: Looking at Microsoft help : `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx` And I do not see Server as a Property of HttpServerUtility

Comment: @Nash I didn't say it was. Re-read my answer. I said the type of the property was HttpServerUtility.

Comment: So I can pass the  var server as the context parameter to DoStuff function?

Comment: @SNash No. You either do one approach or the other. Get the context (and thus the server) from the page via function or constructor parameter or use `HttpContext.Current.Server`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Server` is a property of the page. But looks like you aren't inherit page class in your `a.cs` so it isn't available. You can also use `HttpContext.Current.Server`

`Server` property is instance of [`HttpServerUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility(v=vs.110).aspx), and there are a couple of static methods and a lot of instance methods, so depending on what you want you can also use static way.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Server` doesn't exist in your class.  It *does* exist in the `Page` class as a property.  So when you do access `Server` in your page's code-behind, you're accessing a *property*, not the class itself.

That property can also be accessed here:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server
```

`Current` is a static property on the `HttpContext` class which refers to the current HTTP context, which is initialized by ASP.NET in a running web application.  Note that if you do this, your class will be tightly coupled with a running HTTP context.  This generally isn't a good practice.

Instead, what you might do is *require* an instance of a valid `HttpContext` in your class.  Something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private HttpContext _currentContext;

    public MyClass(HttpContext currentContext)
    {
        _currentContext = currentContext;
    }

    // the rest of your class
}
```

Then any time something needs to create an instance of your class, it also needs to supply the `HttpContext` which your class would use.  This allows your class to be used an tested independently of any given HTTP context, as long as whatever uses it can supply one.

You can further de-couple this if your class doesn't need the *whole* context but instead just needs some component(s) or value(s) from it.  Generally speaking, the less coupled your objects are the more portable and re-usable they are.

Comment: The only reason I need to access Server in this class is to use 'Server.MapPath("~\\bin\\error.txt")'  . So i need whaever you mentioned above?

Comment: @SNash: In that case I would recommend requiring either `HttpContext` or `HttpServerUtility` on the class' constructor.  `HttpServerUtility` requires an active HTTP context in order for that method to work, so at the very least this class is naturally coupled to a web application.  Which one gets passed to the constructor makes little difference.  I'd lean toward narrowing the scope as much as possible, which would require an instance of `HttpServerUtility` on the constructor.